# Push up to the Bitbucket remote repository through gitbash command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bitbucket

Created a repository on bitbucket. Trying to "push up" to the repository, though am unsure exactly what that means?

Also, and more importantly, I get an error when trying to execute two lines:

```
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.com/addyd/toy_app.git/src/master
fatal: remote origin already exists.

Addy@DESKTOP-6L1EGSI MINGW64 /c/Sites/environment/toy_app (master) $
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.com/addyd/toy_app.git/src/master1
```

Any help?

Comment: Try 'git remote add origin <url>.git'

Comment: Then, git commit -m "my first commit", 
and then, git push -u origin master

Answer (score 1):

what it returned if enter the command `git remote -v`

if there is already a git remote origin exist it will print something like

`origin  https://bitbucket.com/addyd/toy_app.git(fetch)
origin  https://bitbucket.com/addyd/toy_app.git(push)`

if it is already there and pointing to the right repository do ACP

`git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push origin branch`

Answer (score 0):

The right command to update change origin would be:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@bitbucket.org/addyd/toy_app.git
```

But you shouldn't need to update origin if it was set before, and if you cloned successfully that repo: add some commits, and then:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: It's actually `.org`. `.com` will still work for SSH, but HTTPS will redirect - and some clients get weird about that.

Comment: @JimRedmond Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: When tried to enter    :$ git push -u origin master
ssh: connect to host bitbucket.org port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: And by add commits you mean what exactly? As of now I'm only following a tutorial from pdf version of "Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Rails 5)
Learn Web Development with Rails," so bear with me...

Comment: Does https://bitbucket.org/addyd/toy_app.git exists? Is it a private repo? Do you have set your public ssh key to your profile? (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html). Does `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` works and displays a Welcome message?